# Cylinder (custom design) Implementation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

[image]

Can you please tell me bout how to implement the design(image link above) in iOS.
The Values shown are actually fetched dynamically and are not static one.
I think, this could be possible only using core graphics.
Or is there any other tricks to implement.
Please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use stretchable images and put them on 3 labels (in the case you posted). The only thing you really need to do is compute their position and add them to subview in correct order.